# Why do I need a wrapper function to recursively call with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, html, css, recursion, settimeout

Currently testing out some stuff with moving an element x amount of pixels in a looped call. I've created a recursive function, and added some delay to avoid the callback from overflowing. I've used setTimeout to create this delay. I'm wondering why I need to wrap my recursive function inside another function when using setTimeout. If I don't, the delay is not added and the browser does the callback has exceeded error in my console. Below is the code that I'm using. It's intended to make "the thing (a ball)" move across the div/box/screen from left to right, over and over.

(I understand requestAnimationFrame is typically used for this sort of thing, but I'm attempting to familiarize myself with javascript through different approaches).

```
function moveThing(pos){
    var currentPos = pos;

    currentPos += 5;

    theThing.style.left = currentPos + "px";

    if( Math.abs(currentPos) >= 900) {
        currentPos = -500;
    }

    console.log(currentPos);
    setTimeout(function(){moveThing(currentPos)}, 100);

}

moveThing(0);
```

Also, if I'm not using correct terminology, feel free to correct. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What else would you do?

Comment: Because `setTimeout` expects a callable function as the first argument, not a function *call*

Comment: @Li357 Ohhh, alright. Simple enough! Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, the answer is: Because you need to pass a function to `setTimeout`. `setTimeout(moveThing(currentPos), 100)` would call `moveThing` and pass its *return* value (which isn't a function) to `setTimeout`.

But note that on any vaguely-modern browser, you can pass `moveThing` itself, you don't need a wrapper. You can replacing your current `setTimeout` call with this:

```
setTimeout(moveThing, 100, currentPos);
```

...which tells `setTimeout` to call `moveThing` in 100ms (or so) passing `currentPos` as its first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you did this:

```
setTimeout(moveThing(currentPos), 100);
```

You'd be invoking it immediately it would be effectively the same as this:

```
var x = moveThing(currentPos);
setTimeout(x, 100);
```

So the function is never delayed, and can never exit, and the call stack limit is eventually reached.

---

If you did this:

```
setTimeout(moveThing, 100);
```

Then it would be delayed, but since the `currentPos` variable is local to the function, it wouldn't get passed along, so it wouldn't work.

---

One option that doesn't involve passing a wrapper function every time would be to make `moveThing` close over the `currentPos` variable. Then the function can be passed directly, and it will always access that same var.

```js
function makeMover(pos, theThing) {
  return function moveThing() {
    pos += 5;

    theThing.style.left = pos + "px";

    if (Math.abs(pos) >= 900) {
      pos = -500;
    }

    console.log(theThing.id, pos);
    setTimeout(moveThing, 100);
  }
}

var mover = makeMover(0, document.querySelector("#theThing"));
mover();

var mover2 = makeMover(0, document.querySelector("#theThing2"));
setTimeout(mover2, 1000);
```

```css
.thing {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
}
#theThing2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id=theThing class=thing></div>
<div id=theThing2 class=thing></div>
```